# qfield identify settings

Tags: qfield, identify

If I click in the map to identify a feature, there are **always** two steps necessary to see the result. I always need to chose a geometry, even if there is only one displayed in the menu. Next to a border 2 are shown.
Is it possible to have only the affected geometry information shown, without a step between? Is there a radius value I can set, or something like this?

Comment: If I click a polygon it displays the Display Name (as specified in Layer Propertied - Display) then I click the Displayed attribute to see all attributes. Is this the second click you mean? Have you set which layers that should be identifiable under Project Propertries - Data Sources, so you dont click multiple layers every time?